# Passing Accessors into WaterfallDialog causes error after first step Bot Framework v4

Tags: c#, .net, dialog, botframework, state-management

I'm having an issue with `BotAccessors` when I pass it from the main dialog into another dialog. I'm motivated to send accessors up because I need to access and then save state within a `UserProfile` from any dialog.
This is how I'm passing it:

```
await dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(SiteReviewDialog.id, _accessors, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

The `SiteReviewDialog` runs its first step fine and prompts the user, but it errors before even getting to the second step (breakpoints do not get hit).
I tried removing all references to `accessors` in the `SiteReviewDialog`, and it seems the only way to fix this is to not pass `accessors` at all. If I pass `accessors` the error I get is: http://freetexthost.com/sdgdilpyxv

From the error, on line 232 is within my `OnTurnAsync`:

```
var dialogContext = await _dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
```

I tried to follow the code execution in the `SiteReviewDialog` from the first `AddStep(async (stepContext, cancellationToken)` and it exits out line by line then hits `OnTurnAsync` and gets to line 232 then errors. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain what's going on first: the parameter you're passing the `_accessors` to is reserved for an "options" object for the Dialog. This would be something like settings for how the Dialog should behave. For example, in the case of prompts this is always a `PromptOptions` subclass. These options objects get serialized and stored on the stack for the execution lifetime of the dialog, so the reason you're getting an exception passing your `_accessors` is because it contains types that are not serializable. So, long story short, you don't want to pass your accessors this way.

Accessors are effectively singletons and what you would want to do is pass them through the constructor chain of your dialogs. So you would take `IStatePropertyAccessor<T>` (or an "accessors" class if you've decided to follow that pattern) to your `SiteReviewDialog` constructor and then make sure that passes it on to any child dialogs it creates via their constructors. NOTE: dialogs themselves should really be created as singletons as well.

From there it's just a matter of using the accessor when you need it because you always give it a `ITurnContext` from which it should be loading its data and the singleton instance uses identifiers specific to that context to ensure the correct data is loaded.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response and clarification on why this is the wrong approach. I'm a little confused about how to add this to the constructor of my `SiteReviewDialog` still. In my main dialog I have `_dialogs.Add(SiteReviewDialog.Instance);` in its constructor. `Instance` is defined inside `SiteReviewDialog` as `public static SiteReviewDialog Instance { get; } = new SiteReviewDialog(id);` (`id` is defined inside `SiteReviewDialog`) How can I pass accessors from my main dialog into the constructor if the constructor is called from within `SiteReviewDialog`?

Comment: Well that "Instance" pattern is just that: a pattern. It's not the only way to do it and now you need to actually create the instance yourself so that you can pass through parameters to the constructor, you can't really use that pattern any more. Instead you'd need to do: `_dialogs.Add(new SiteReviewDialog(SiteReviewDialog.id, _accessors));`

Comment: That worked great, I can't believe I didn't think of that... Thank you.

Comment: Ah, great to hear it. May I ask where you came across that `Instance` pattern? If it's in the samples or docs I will want to have a discussion with the SDK team about it.

Comment: @craigbot When you have a sec, can you also please make sure to mark this as the answer to your question and/or upvote it so other people might find it useful as well? Thanks! 

Comment: For sure, I didn't have upvote capabilities before but done now! I honestly can't remember where I came across that Instance pattern, but it is so obviously bad that I'm ashamed to have used it :) When the rest of my team comes back in tomorrow we'll look into where it came from a little more. Doesn't seem to be in the samples.

Comment: I found the repo I got this pattern from: https://github.com/jamesemann/bot-framework-v4-intro-dotnet-core and it is in `demo7dialogs` within `BankingBot.cs`